# Execute Selenium Grid in non headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, grid

I have the below code to run Tests in headless mode. I want to know how to turn off headless mode to Running tests in actual browser for debugging purpose.

```
public static void InitBrowser(BrowserEnum browserName)
        {
            const string _seleniumGridUrl = "http://devops-seleniumhub.vuturegroup.local:4444/wd/hub";
            switch (browserName)
            {
                case BrowserEnum.Chrome:
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");


                        remoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(_seleniumGridUrl), chromeOptions.ToCapabilities());
                        remoteDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
                        remoteDriver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
                        ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(remoteDriver);
                        ngDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
                        driver = remoteDriver;
                        Drivers.Add(BrowserEnum.Chrome, ngDriver);
                    }
                    break;}}
```

When I remove the headless argument, I get the below error

```
Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 175 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:19.891Z'
System info: host: 'devops-lseln01', ip: '192.168.10.16', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: About your error, this SO question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the following line which passes the "headless" argument:

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
```